# Doctrine 2 Result Cache

Tags: php, mysql, caching, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I would like to use Doctrine 2's result cache on Zend Framework 2 project like this :

```
$query->useResultCache(true, 3600, 'test');
```

But it doesn't work.

This is my configuration file :

```
<?php
return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' =>'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host'     => 'localhost',
                    'port'     => '3306',
                    'user'     => 'root',
                    'password' => '',
                    'dbname'   => 'skeleton',
                    'charset'  => 'utf8',
                    'driverOptions' => array (1002 => 'SET NAMES utf8'),
                )
            )
        ),
        'configuration' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'metadata_cache'    => 'array',
                'query_cache'       => 'array',
                'result_cache'      => 'array',
                'driver'            => 'orm_default',
                'generate_proxies'  => true,
                'proxy_dir'         => 'data/DoctrineORMModule/Proxy',
                'proxy_namespace'   => 'DoctrineORMModule\Proxy',
                'filters'           => array()
            )
        ),
    )
);
```

**So my question : What is missing in my code?**

Comment: Define "it doesn't work". How did you measure it?

Comment: I've made a select query with cache then edit entries. When i make select query again i can see the changes on entries, that mean the result was not save in cache from the first select. I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the ArrayCache implementation:

```
'result_cache'      => 'array',
```

The ArrayCache is a "fake" cache, it just puts values into an array, which disappears at the end of the request, like everything else in PHP. You need to use a cache that stays alive between requests, like APC, Memcache, XCache. I would give pointers on how to do this, but I'm not familiar with Zend2, check what the docs say, you probably just need to change the aforementioned line to "apc".